# React js installation for different projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently new to reactjs I installed it & I have only one doubt that every time do I need to download entire reactjs(which was almost of 100mb) for different projects or is there any other way to do it

Comment: I think the most common way to go about it is to use CRA (Create-React-App - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) when starting a new React application. But yes, you need to have React installed.

Comment: Yes, you have to install it everytime when you start with a new project. But that's not the size of your application. It includes many packages, like webpack etc. Once you build your project it will not have that much size.

Comment: If you're using the same version of react in multiple projects on your machine, your package manager will cache the downloads normally. So the same version of react isn't downloaded again, it will simply be copied from the cache directory to your project's node_modules folder.

Comment: Means for the same version if I create two different projects then it won't cost me 100mb, it will be using cache of previous project right?